# Check if a javascript array contains all elements or part of element values of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I'm looking for a solution to the following problem:

```
var haystack_1 = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange'];
var haystack_2 = ['banana', 'apple', 'lemon'];
var haystack_3 = ['banana', 'apple', 'bloodorange'];
var needle_1 = ['apple', 'banana', 'or'];
```

Result when matching should be:

```
//needle_1 haystack_1 -> true
//needle_1 haystack_2 -> false
//needle_1 haystack_3 -> true
```

Already working for whole words:

```
function arrayContainsAnotherArray(needle, haystack){
  for(var i = 0; i < needle.length; i++){ 
    if(haystack.indexOf(needle[i]) === -1)
       return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

This works perfectly for exact matches like:

```
var needle_2 = ['apple', 'banana', 'bloodorange'];
return arrayContainsAnotherArray(needle_2 , haystack_1); //false
return arrayContainsAnotherArray(needle_2 , haystack_2); //false
return arrayContainsAnotherArray(needle_2 , haystack_3); //true
```

How can I combine this function with matching parts of words, also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just a slight function modification....

```
function arrayContainsAnotherArray(needle, haystack){
  for(var i = 0; i < needle.length; i++){ 
    if(!haystack.some(hay => hay.indexOf(needle[i]) > -1))
       return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

just instead checks if "there is not some item in the haystack that contains the neddle, return false"

note that this is case sensitive.

Comment: Wow, this is fantastic! Works perfectly! Thank you so much! Any concerns about the performance? Because there are a lot of haystacks.

Comment: the performance is pretty much maxed here. other commenters suggested the use of the "every" function which is good clean syntax, but will perform the same as both break as soon as a "false" is found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#every()` and  `Array#some()` along with `String#includes()` for partial matches

```js
var haystack_1 = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange'];
var haystack_2 = ['banana', 'apple', 'lemon'];
var haystack_3 = ['banana', 'apple', 'bloodorange'];

function arrayContainsAnotherArray(needle, haystack){
  return haystack.every(s=> needle.some(v => s.includes(v)))
  
}

var needle_2 = ['apple', 'banana', 'bloodorange'];
console.log(arrayContainsAnotherArray(needle_2 , haystack_1)); //false
console.log(arrayContainsAnotherArray(needle_2 , haystack_2)); //false
console.log(arrayContainsAnotherArray(needle_2 , haystack_3)); //true
```

Comment: good use of every for cleaner syntax, but some is slightly optimized over find

Comment: @bryan60 not sure how much more optimized it really is other than what it actually returns. Both break when condition is met

Comment: true actually, my bad.  Forgot find will break at first find

Answer (score 0):

You could check the needles agains the haystack with `includes`.

```js
function check(needle, haystack) {
    return haystack.every(h => needle.some(n => h.includes(n)));
}

var haystack_1 = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange'];
var haystack_2 = ['banana', 'apple', 'lemon'];
var haystack_3 = ['banana', 'apple', 'bloodorange'];
var needle_1 = ['apple', 'banana', 'or'];

console.log(check(needle_1, haystack_1)); // true
console.log(check(needle_1, haystack_2)); // false
console.log(check(needle_1, haystack_3)); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `every` with `includes` for checking all the parts:

```js
function arrayContainsAnotherArray(needle, haystack) {
  return needle.every(el => !!haystack.find(item => item.includes(el)));
}

var haystack_1 = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange'];
var haystack_2 = ['banana', 'apple', 'lemon'];
var haystack_3 = ['banana', 'apple', 'bloodorange'];
var needle_1 = ['apple', 'banana', 'or'];

console.log(arrayContainsAnotherArray(needle_1, haystack_1));
console.log(arrayContainsAnotherArray(needle_1, haystack_2));
console.log(arrayContainsAnotherArray(needle_1, haystack_3));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works matching with regex instead of string equality, but it matches the needle anywhere in the haystack, so it returns true for your second example because apple and banana are found.

```
function needle_matches(haystack, needles) {
  for(var i = 0; i < needles.length; i++){
    if(haystack.some(function(e) { e.match(needles[i]) })) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: this function does not work.  It will return true on the first needle that matches.